# How do I avoid extra spaces in a PHP string after str_replace functions?

Tags: php, string

I have an app where people can enter their date of birth (dob), time of birth (tob), sex, weight and hair color.

In my code, I have a string like this:

```
$allfields="'dob', 'tob', 'sex', 'weight', 'hair'";
```

My code then checks each category to see if it was entered by the user.  If a category was entered, nothing changes to the string.  But if, for example, sex was not entered, I would want to remove "'sex'," from the `$allfields` string

Any potential removal of text from the string is done by these five functions:

```
$allfields=str_replace("'dob',", "", $allfields);
$allfields=str_replace("'tob',", "", $allfields);
$allfields=str_replace("'sex',", "", $allfields);
$allfields=str_replace("'weight',", "", $allfields);
$allfields=str_replace(", 'hair'", "", $allfields);
```

Notice in the last one, how I search for ", 'hair'" (with leading comma). This is because if hair was not entered, I want to remove it from the string, but if I just remove 'hair', then the string would end with a comma, which would break my code where i use the string later on.

However, it seems extra spaces occur when things are removed, so as a result, after all checks are done and in cases where 'hair' SHOULD have been removed, it's not.  The string looks like this, for example:

```
'dob', 'tob',   'hair'
```

The reason hair isn't removed from the string is that there is extra space between the comma after 'tob' and 'hair', so it wouldn't find ", 'hair'" exactly (it's actually ",      'hair'"). So it's not an exact match and thus doesn't get removed.

I'm open to suggestions but is the best way to attack this to remove extra spaces from `$allfields` before the 'hair' check is done?  Is the best way to do that using the same str_replace function that looks for spaces and replaces them with nothing, or would I run into the same issue?

Comment: You might be better off using a simple array rather than a string for each element.  Then you can foreach on the array and check for each value rather than try to pull it out of a string.  The code can check for each element and then append it to an array rather than adding to a string.  My 2¢.  The next easiest way would be to just explode the string by comma and it should remove white space automatically while returning an array.

Comment: This sounds like a bad way to structure the incoming data. Why not have individual fields for each data point?

Comment: You can remove all spaces first by `str_replace(" ","",$allfields);`

Comment: Thanks, all useful comments.  I will look into using an array instead of a long string so the fields remain separate data points from one another. Thanks again!